# WP_Nav Highlight Parent Issue

Tags: php, menus, css

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight the parent nav of a page and becoming stuck.

I've seen something like this :

```
<li <?php if(is_page('services')) { echo 'class="current_page_item"'; } ?> >
     <a href="#">Services</a>
</li>
```

I have different post types going on and I've split each post type into a page, the problem begins when I click down into the "services" tab and click a "service request" the blog navigation highlights instead of the services one.

How can I fix this? I don't mind using PHP or CSS for this as the site is for myself.

Comment: please post whatever code you are using to create your nav

Comment: just using the standard wp_nav at the moment.

        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

Comment: if you use the walker you do need to add any PHP to highlight current page item, there are CSS classes made for that : .current-menu-item {} and current_page_item {}

Comment: have tried all variations of current_page_item etc the ancestor class is working at the moment for parent pages...